# Срабатывает FocusListener при изменении текста

Tags: java, android, focus

Есть форма **EditText** на которой висит **View.OnFocusChangeListener**. 
При редактировании **EditText** (вводе символов, удалении) постоянно срабатывает событие **onFocusChange**

```
editText_size.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(hasFocus)
                return;

            EditText et = (EditText) view;

            Log.i("MyShop", "focus change");

            //Если установленное значение не число
            if(!Util.isNumeric(et.getText().toString(), true)) {
                et.setText("1");
            }

        }
    });
```

**Что я не знаю и почему это так? Как исправить?**

Comment: Нашёл решение проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730610/edittext-inside-listview-will-not-stay-focused